# C# get time between two datetime range

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Hello everybody i have asp.net mvc4 application where i made countdown something like this:

How i can get how many days, hours, minutes and seconds are remaining with two daetime range

i have tried this does not working on minutes .`TotalMinutes`

```
datetime.TotalDays();
```

[image]

Comment: `remaining with two daetime range` - what are you mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
Timespan remtime = YourLaunchDateTime - DateTime.Now;
```

Then:

Use `remtime.Days` for Days

Use `remtime.Hours` for Hours

Use `remtime.Minutes` for Minutes

Use `remtime.Seconds` for Seconds

Do not use any `Total...` property as it converts all time into that entity.

You are using `remtime.TotalMinutes`. This will convert your Time into Minutes.

For eg. if 3 Hours are left this will return 180 Minutes (bcoz 3 * 60 = 180)

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeSpan span = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
```

`span` will contain needed data.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Minutes` instead of `TotalMinutes`. `TotalMinutes` makes sum of all minutes within the timespan.